# Different ways of maintaining session

Tags: session

What are the different ways of maintaining session in a browser?

Consider a scenario;
I am browsing a secure site in Firefox and the browser crashes. Now when I open the browser again and I do Restore tabs, my previous session is restored back ? Is that handled automatically by the browser OR is it code-based ?

Also can we control session based on tab close vs window close, etc

Is there any connect between maintaining the session at server vs having the same at client side?

Answer (score 0):

```
What are the different ways of maintaining session in a browser?
```

Different ways to maintaining sessions are :-

Cookies ( Most Standard way )
Url Rewriting
Html Forms hidden fields

> Consider a scenario; I am browsing a secure site in Firefox and the
>   browser crashes. Now when I open the browser again and I do Restore
>   tabs, my previous session is restored back ? Is that handled
>   automatically by the browser OR is it code-based ?

It is handled by browser automatically if it was cookie based, other wise you will manage that.

> Also can we control session based on tab close vs window close, etc

On server you can control session just by time, mean when it will invalid, but if you want to do something that will invalid session when close tab then according to me you can bind on close event in javascript and then delete the cookie that was used to manage the session, PHPSESSION ( in php's case )

> Is there any connect between maintaining the session at server vs
>   having the same at client side?

Yup :)

when you create a session actually you are sending a cookie.

Think you are coding in php, and you create a session, now what happens is:  a file will be created on the server (file is the default way to handle session in php but you can also change that) and a unique id will also create on server that will represent that session, think you create a session so a file will created with name sjflsj3lrh324l2hjlskdjfl3hl.session  and a unique id will also created ex:- sjflsj3lrh324l2hjlskdjfl3hl.

Now when you store anything in session you actually are storing that in this file, and when you will send response to browser, you will also send a cookie on browser and the cookie value will be this id. So next time when you reopen that web, browser will first check if there was any cookie received from this domain before. If yes, then send that with request, and then on server php will check if request contains any cookie with it. If so, then it will check if that name file exists, and if exists mean there was a session. It will then open that file and all variables values that was saved in it will be restored in php variables.